# Clipping raster with shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, clip, lidar

I want to clip a raster (Lidar LC81140632013197LGN00 which I downloaded from Earth Explorer) with  shapefile in QGIS version 2.0.1.

Which plugin in QGIS could I use it?

Comment: Do you want to clip a raster or LiDAR (point cloud) data? Different data types are likely to give different solutions.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

If your raster data comes in a format that QGIS can load, you can do it inside QGIS with `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper`.

Make sure your clipping polygon shapefile has the same CRS as the raster. It might be necessary to save the raster data as Geotiff, if the source file does not have CRS information.